# how to write a sqlite trigger in JS wrapper

Tags: javascript, sqlite, triggers, insert

Let's assume 2 tables:
table1[idTble1, elmt1_T1, elmt2_T1]
table2[idTble2, id_Tble1, elmt1_T2, index]
I want to create a trigger that runs after `Insert On table1`, and Insert a new row in Table2 where

```
id_Tble1 = new.idTble1
elmt1_T2 = new.elmt1_T1
```

and index is a value set by the user and that is only saved in Table2.
I have tried the following

```
var createTrigger = "CREATE TRIGGER triggerInsert AFTER INSERT ON Table1 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO Table2 (id_Tble1, elmt1_T2, index) VALUES (:new.idTble1, :new.elmt_T1, ?); END;";
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(createTrigger, [i], null, onError);
    });
```

but i got an error (could not prepare statement (1 near "REFERENCING": syntax error).

Comment: Syntax error is because SQL is not valid JS. Looks like there other errors too. First thing, put quotes around your SQL and assign it to a variable `createTrigger`

Comment: I'm not seeing the `REFERENCING` clause in the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html). Have you tried it without this clause?

Comment: My bad, I reedited my post and added var createTrigger =
I took of REFERENCING clause, now the error is: (1 near ".": syntax error)

Comment: What's the new error? Next obvious thing is that you shouldn't name a variable `new` and that you should be passing that variable to `tx.executeSql` but still not enough to tell. Is this Node.js?

Comment: from what i found on the web, a new element inserted in Table1 for instance is referenced as :new.FieldName in Table2 Insert. No Node.js, it's client side JS.

Answer (score 1):

After several looooong hours, I got it working, at least partially. I have to admit that the software SQLiteManager, even in demo version, was helpful in debugging the code.
Here is the trigger that works:

```
var createTrigger = "CREATE TRIGGER triggerInsert AFTER INSERT ON Table1 BEGIN INSERT INTO Table2 (id_Tble1, elmt1_T2, index) VALUES (new.idTble1, new.elmt_T1, new.index); END";
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(createTrigger, [], null, onError);
    });
```

When I say partially, is because I have not been able to have the trigger use the value of 'index' in the form. So what I had to do was to create a new field (index) in table1.